# javafx print dialog shows up on mac but not on windows

Tags: javafx, printing

I implemented the Javafx PrinterJob on one of my projects to print some nodes.
When I run it on my mac everything works as expected but when I copy the jar file to my Windows machine and I run it there, the app works well but the print dialog doesn't show up.

Here is my NodePrinter class

```
public class NodePrinter {

static PrinterJob job;

public static void print(VBox node, int numberOfPages) {
    job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
    if (job != null && job.showPrintDialog(node.getScene().getWindow())) {
        Printer printer = job.getPrinter();
        PageLayout pageLayout = printer.createPageLayout(Paper.A4, PageOrientation.PORTRAIT, Printer.MarginType.HARDWARE_MINIMUM);

        AnchorPane root;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPages; i++) {
            root = (AnchorPane) node.getChildren().get(0);
            start(root, pageLayout);
            node.getChildren().remove(root);
        }

        job.endJob();
    }

}

public static boolean start(AnchorPane root, PageLayout pageLayout) {

    double printableWidth = pageLayout.getPrintableWidth();
    double printableHeight = pageLayout.getPrintableHeight();

    double width = root.getWidth();
    double height = root.getHeight();

    if (width > printableWidth) {
        root.setMaxWidth(printableWidth);
    } else if(width < printableWidth) {
        root.setMinWidth(printableWidth);
    }

        double scaleX = 0.95;

        double scaleY;
        if (height + 100 > printableHeight) {
            if (height > 1100) {
                scaleY = printableHeight/ (height + 200);
            } else {
                scaleY = printableHeight/ (height + 100);
            }
        } else {
            scaleY = 1;
        }

        Scale scale = new Scale(scaleX, scaleY);

        root.getTransforms().add(scale);
        boolean success = job.printPage(pageLayout, root);
        root.getTransforms().remove(scale);
        return success;
    }
}
```

And I use it like this

```
    Stage window = App.getPreloaderWindow();
    App.dataPreloader.start(window);

    Task<Void> printTask = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            this.updateMessage("Starting the Printer Job...");
            NodePrinter.print((VBox) root.lookup("#printView"), 4);

            return null;
        }
    };

    // binds progress of progress bars to progress of task:
    dataPreloader.activateProgressBar(printTask);

    printTask.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
        window.close();
    });
    Thread thread = new Thread(printTask);
    thread.start();
```

On mac I the codes work well and i get the print dialog. A screenshot of it is shown below:

[image: Print dialog showing on Mac]

But on windows the task never get completed and my preloader shows indefinitely.

**Edit:**

I finally exported the project as a zip file and imported it back on windows, built from there and the print dialog worked. But when I run the distribution jar out of the netbeans ide the print dialog doesn't work anymore.

I getting very confused with this behavior.

Comment: I am guessing here but I think your problem is altering `Node` within a `Thread`.

Comment: See what happens when you run the code with out the `Thread`.

Comment: But it's working well on Mac

Comment: Makes no difference.

Comment: Ok let me comment out the thread and re-try

Comment: I have tried without the Thread but still not working

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is.

Comment: What JRE/JDK version do you use? Are you sure there isn't any output on the console when the print-dialog doesn't show up (You could dump System.out and System.err to a text-file or debug the jar)? When you create the jar-file on windows does it work on mac?

Comment: 1-Do use any Obfuscation ?
2-Do you use the same version of JDK for both MAC & WINDOWS 
3-Does your jar work fine in MAC and WINDOWS not , if yes please make sure that you're copy the DIST to windows to run on WIN
4-Can you write your import library

Comment: when I run the application in netbeans ide the print-dialog shows up both on mac and on windows but when I run the jar out of netbeans the print works on mac but not on windows

Comment: There is no error in console

Answer (score 0):

This is simply a file dependency issue in netbeans on Java FX deploy

Please watch this to see why its failing on distro.

FYI JAVAFX will be removed from Java releases in the near future. So make sure your adding the entire .jar as a dependency.
[Video of why it fails](http://www.jeremiahstillings.net/java-fx-deploy-help/)